# How can I make an image from HDD without any traces so No one even expert would be able to spot is happened?

Tags: linux, image, copy, dd

### Hello, guys!

Well, basically I just wanna make an image of hdd and then run it on another machine, because I don't wanna leave any traces, no one should be able to see if machine has been booted. So therefore I wanna make a copy of the system and then run it so this will be mine copy then and I don't care about booting trace on it.

I need to check the presence of some special programs on it. It's my purpose. But when I will be in process of copying I gotta be absolutely sure I won't leave any traces on original system. I would be glad to see any answers, guys. **Thank you beforehand.**

Answer (score 0):

Don't boot from it. Optimally use Live USB operating system (Ubuntu has pretty good support for this https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu ).

Then mount the HDD as read-only.

Now you can copy it using dd or what you wish and you won't affect a single bit on the HDD. I can't guarantee the HDD won't store any traces of reading from it internally, but that would not be circumvented without actually disassembling the HDD.